# How do I use White soapstone?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I cant use my white soapstone. I've been trying to use it and I cannot figure out how.

Comment: white sign soapstone

Comment: maybe you are joining Champion Covenant.

Comment: i will try leaving champion covenant

Answer (score 9):

There's a few reasons that you wouldn't be able to use the soapstone:

- You're offline (at the moment that I'm writing this, it appears the PC servers are having a bit of trouble)
- You're in the Champion's Covenant
- You've burned an effigy at the bonfire for the zone you're in

If you're offline, there's no much you can do but go back online. You can drop the Champion's Covenant by talking to the cat in Majula. If you've burned an effigy at a bonfire, the effects should wear off in about 30 minutes.

Finally, if you're getting a message similar to "Failed to create summon sign"... Well, I never figured out what causes this or how to fix it. I had one character on the PS3 that suffered from this and never recovered, but all my other characters were fine.

I also made a video explaining the first two items on the list, but there's not really any additional information other than maybe where to find the cat.

Comment: There are, that I've seen, two reasons you cannot use a soapstone:1) Someone is invading your world.  You'll notice the exits into other areas throw up a dark grey fog, and shortly thereafter you'll get the "You're being invaded" message.  2) The other is for certain areas that do not allow co-operative play, in which case you cannot place a sign, or find any other players signs to co-op.  (Such as the two rat bosses, you cannot help or be helped in either fight).  Also, the second instance of the Pursuer in the lava area.